# How to scroll items simultaneously when they are within a table?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a huge table where I want to introduce scrolling for the data.  I don't want to separate into two tables, but scroll the data simultaneously. Here is a simplified code in JSFiddle and below:

https://jsfiddle.net/oy4pdz8t/7/

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>fixed</td>
  <td>
    <div id="scrolling1" class=" linked">
      <div class="data">1</div>
      <div class="data">2</div>
      <div class="data">3</div>
      <div class="data">4</div>
      <div class="data">5</div>
      
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>fixed</td>
  <td>
    <div  id="scrolling2" class=" linked">
      <div class="data">1</div>
      <div class="data">2</div>
      <div class="data">3</div>
      <div class="data">4</div>
      <div class="data">5</div>
      
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
#scrolling1{
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

#scrolling2{
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

.data{
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background: red;
  
}
```

And the jQuery is:

```
$(function(){

    $('.linked').scroll(function(){
        $('.linked').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());    
    })

})
```

Is it possible to make the two scrolling sections scroll simultaneously. As mentioned above, I don't want to have to touch the table structure, since it would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.linked').on('scroll', function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollLeft();
  $('.linked').scrollLeft(y);
});
```

```css
#scrolling1{
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

#scrolling2{
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

.data{
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background: red;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>fixed</td>
  <td>
    <div id="scrolling1" class="linked">
      <div class="data">1</div>
      <div class="data">2</div>
      <div class="data">3</div>
      <div class="data">4</div>
      <div class="data">5</div>
      
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>fixed</td>
  <td>
    <div  id="scrolling2" class="linked">
      <div class="data">1</div>
      <div class="data">2</div>
      <div class="data">3</div>
      <div class="data">4</div>
      <div class="data">5</div>
      
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can use jQuery's scroll functions.

Explanation:

| Line | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `$('.linked').on('scroll', function() {` | Activate on scroll of either of the `.linked`s |
| `var y = $(this).scrollLeft();` | Save the scroll position |
| `$('.linked').scrollLeft(y);` | Scroll both of them to that position |
| `});` | Close the block |

When the top one is scrolled, this happens:

[image: demo]

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `scrollLeft()` instead of `scrollTop()`.
`scrollLeft()` is for horizontal scroll while `scrollTop()` is for vertical scroll.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.linked').scroll(function() {
    $('.linked').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
  })

})
```

```css
#scrolling1 {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

#scrolling2 {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>fixed</td>
    <td>
      <div id="scrolling1" class=" linked">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>

      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fixed</td>
    <td>
      <div id="scrolling2" class=" linked">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>

      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh! Used one less variable than me. You win!

Comment: Both answers helped me equally, had to choose one. To show the variable in an extra step actually explained the link to me. Thanks Gentlemen!!